# Routing error calling controller with AJAX in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to call my controller from my view using AJAX, but I got an error on the routes. At the moment I am not able to fix it.

```
<script>
     function finance_module(data){
          input1 = data['data_output'][0];
          input2 = data['data_output'][1];
           $.ajax({ 
              type: 'POST', 
              url: '/calculation', 
              data: {"data":[input1,input2]}, 
              dataType: 'json', 
              success: function(data){ //Sending the output to a function
              console.log('success', data); 
               } 
             }); 
      };
</script>
```

My controller: `calculation_controller.rb`

```
class CalculationController < ApplicationController    
  def index     

  end

  def create    
           input1 = params[:data][0].to_i
           input2 = params[:data][1].to_i
           data = input1 * 5;
           return data
end
```

end

My routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :energycalc
    end
    namespace :v2 do
       resources :energycalcsb
    end

  end

  get 'calculation/index'
  post 'calculation/index'
  root 'calculation#index'

end
```

I am getting this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/calculation"):
```

My routes:

```
_index GET    /api/v1/energycalc(.:format)            api/v1/energycalc#index
                          POST   /api/v1/energycalc(.:format)            api/v1/energycalc#create
    new_api_v1_energycalc GET    /api/v1/energycalc/new(.:format)        api/v1/energycalc#new
   edit_api_v1_energycalc GET    /api/v1/energycalc/:id/edit(.:format)   api/v1/energycalc#edit
        api_v1_energycalc GET    /api/v1/energycalc/:id(.:format)        api/v1/energycalc#show
                          PATCH  /api/v1/energycalc/:id(.:format)        api/v1/energycalc#update
                          PUT    /api/v1/energycalc/:id(.:format)        api/v1/energycalc#update
                          DELETE /api/v1/energycalc/:id(.:format)        api/v1/energycalc#destroy
api_v2_energycalcsb_index GET    /api/v2/energycalcsb(.:format)          api/v2/energycalcsb#index
                          POST   /api/v2/energycalcsb(.:format)          api/v2/energycalcsb#create
  new_api_v2_energycalcsb GET    /api/v2/energycalcsb/new(.:format)      api/v2/energycalcsb#new
 edit_api_v2_energycalcsb GET    /api/v2/energycalcsb/:id/edit(.:format) api/v2/energycalcsb#edit
      api_v2_energycalcsb GET    /api/v2/energycalcsb/:id(.:format)      api/v2/energycalcsb#show
                          PATCH  /api/v2/energycalcsb/:id(.:format)      api/v2/energycalcsb#update
                          PUT    /api/v2/energycalcsb/:id(.:format)      api/v2/energycalcsb#update
                          DELETE /api/v2/energycalcsb/:id(.:format)      api/v2/energycalcsb#destroy
        calculation_index GET    /calculation/index(.:format)            calculation#index
                          POST   /calculation/index(.:format)            calculation#index
                     root GET    /                                       calculation#index
```

Until now I have tried to fix it without success. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You are expecting **/calculation** will call your calculations controller create action. For that you should add

```
post 'calculation'=> 'calculations#create, as: :calculation
```

this will give you post route

```
calculation POST /calculation(.:format) calculation#create
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't named the route the path is:

```
calculation_index POST /calculation/index(.:format) calculation#index
```

Running `rake routes` diagnoses this issue immediately.

Name the route:

```
post "calculation/index", as: "calculation"
```

`rake routes` now shows what you expect:

```
➜  test_post_route  rake routes
     Prefix Verb URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
calculation POST /calculation/index(.:format) calculation#index
```

Comment: Im still receiving the same error. I updated my question

Comment: @kaka Your routes show precisely what I said. If you're trying to call `create` then you need to specify that in your route.